# When i configure the DYNDNS account in my local router it is not work

Tags: networking, dyndns

I have create a account in dyndns.com to access my dvr through internet

I have fowerd the port too, bbut it does not work

Router TP-LINK Model No: TD-W8950ND

Answer (score 0):

First: go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ and see if the port is even open.

If not, then forget all the other stuff and try to get this open by configuring Virtual Servers. *Keep in mind that the Routers MGMT port is on port 80 - change the Router port if you are keeping the DVR on port 80.*

Second: Once you know the port is in fact open, try to access this DVR by the IP address.

If that doesn't work try to mess with the first step again.

If this does work then try to configure the DynamicDNS in the Router.

When you see that the Status says connected in the Router, then you should be able to use the domain name to access the DVR.